# MSI ignoring %programfiles% environment variable

Tags: windows-installer, program-files

I have a MSI'd application I am installing, ignoring the `%programfiles%` environment variable. From a procmon trace, it seems to be using the value of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir` instead.

Why might it be doing this (I mean is it common practice to use this value, or is this the only value that is exposed to MSI builders)?

Why does this other registry value exist, when `HKCU\Environment\ProgramFiles` & `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ProgramFiles` are available for use?

Comment: No, it uses SHGetKnownFolderPath().  The registry keys were retained for appcompat reasons, too many programs reading the registry instead of using the api function.  Altering %ProgramFiles% is never going to do what you hope it will do.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the problem is with reading the registry, instead of using API functions, but I presume the latter one is a more clean/error checked/etc way. Interesting however, as the program seems to be checking both. Probably out of scope, but do you know how to move the Program Files directory safely (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700/en-us)?

Comment: You're right, that's off topic here.  Ask at superuser.com.  If you are going to write an installer that moves the Program Files directory then you'd better contract a [service like this](http://www.bodyguardservice.net/eng/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Installer exposes the [ProgramFilesFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ProgramFiles64Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties.  The behavior is documented but the implementation is not.  You should only rely on the properties and no other technique.

Officially, you need a 64bit MSI using the ProgramFiles64Folder property to go to C:\Program Files\ on a 64bit machine.  Even if you use a custom action to explicitly set your directory to this path in a 32bit MSI, the installer will intercept the path and redirect it to what it thinks is the intended directory.  This is for application compatibility purposes.

There is an undocumented way to subvert this behavior.  Use a custom action to obtain the intended folder and convert it to a short path (C:\Progra~1).  The installer does not detect this as invalid and will allow it through.  Use this at your own risk.